# Python tkinter - how to create a realtime x-y plot which scrolls left off canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a Phyton app using tkinter for the GUI, and want to plot real time sensor data in a never ending X-Y graph that scrolls the old data off the left hand side of the canvas. It's ok for the old data to be lost.

I'd prefer not to use matplotlib as my needs are simple and will be targeting a RPi 3 so not a lot of resources. I'm thinking of just using tkinter "create_line" for each new sample. It's just the scrolling that I'm unsure about.

Comment: Yes, scrolling is possible - have you tried?

Comment: keep values on list and add new value at the beginning and remove last value - this  way you move values in list - when you redraw line using new values then it will move on canvas. And use `after(milliseconds, redraw)` to run function `redraw` which will change line on canvas.

Comment: example [canvas-bouncing-ball/main-many-balls.py](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/__canvas__/canvas-bouncing-ball) use list to keep positions of many balls (which follows first ball) and `after()` to run function which move them to new positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Example keeps values `y` on list `data` and uses `after` to run function `move` every 500ms (0.5s) which removes first value from list and add new value at the end and then remove all lines from canvas to draw new ones.

It could keep IDs of lines on list, and moves lines but current method seems simpler.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk
import random

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

SCREEN_WIDTH  = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 200

DISTANCE = 50
NUMBER = (SCREEN_WIDTH // DISTANCE) + 1

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

def move():
    # remove first
    data.pop(0)

    # add last
    data.append(random.randint(0,SCREEN_HEIGHT))

    # remove all lines
    canvas.delete('all')

    # draw new lines        
    for x, (y1, y2) in enumerate(zip(data, data[1:])):
        x1 = x * DISTANCE
        x2 = (x+1) * DISTANCE  # x1 + DISTANCE
        canvas.create_line([x1, y1, x2, y2])

    # run again after 500ms (0.5s)
    root.after(500, move)

# --- main --- (lower_case names)

# data at start
data = [random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT) for _ in range(NUMBER)]


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=SCREEN_WIDTH, height=SCREEN_HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()

# start animation    
move()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** `DISTANCE = 2`

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

This code use two little different classes to draw graph. Now they need only append new element to move line

```
def move():
    graph.append(random.randint(0,SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    graph_canvas.append(random.randint(0,SCREEN_HEIGHT))

    # run again after 100ms (0.1s)
    root.after(100, move)
```

Class `Graph` gets canvas as argument so teoreticly you can add graph to existing canvas. But it remove all object so it would need changes to resolve this problem.

Class `GraphCanvas` is widget which resize `Canvas` and doesn't need existing canvas. Teoreticly you can add other elements like to normal canvas but again problem is that it removes all object and it would need changes in code.

It would use `canvas.move(offset_x, offset_y)` to move lines and then it wouldn't need to delete lines. Or maybe it would use `canvas.create_polygon` but it would have to first create list with pairs `(x,y)`

Both change "distance" between point so they use all space when canvas change size horizontally. Vertically it would need recalculations.

I added colors to see if canvases change size in window.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SCREEN_WIDTH  = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 200

DISTANCE = 20
NUMBER = (SCREEN_WIDTH // DISTANCE) + 1

# --- classes --- (CamelCaseNames)

class Graph(object):

    def __init__(self, canvas, data, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.data = data
        self.draw()

    def append(self, item, remove_first=True):
        if remove_first:
            self.data.pop(0)
        self.data.append(item)
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        # new distance if size changed
        self.distance = int(self.canvas.winfo_width())/len(self.data)+1

        # remove all lines
        self.canvas.delete('all')

        # draw new lines        
        for x, (y1, y2) in enumerate(zip(self.data, self.data[1:])):
            x1 = x * self.distance
            x2 = (x+1) * self.distance  # x1 + self.distance
            self.canvas.create_line([x1, y1, x2, y2])

class GraphCanvas(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master, data, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.data = data
        self.draw()

    def append(self, item, remove_first=True):
        if remove_first:
            self.data.pop(0)
        self.data.append(item)
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        # new distance if size changed
        self.distance = int(self.winfo_width())/len(self.data)+1

        # remove all lines
        self.delete('all')

        # draw new lines        
        for x, (y1, y2) in enumerate(zip(self.data, self.data[1:])):
            x1 = x * self.distance
            x2 = (x+1) * self.distance  # x1 + self.distance
            self.create_line([x1, y1, x2, y2])

# --- functions --- (lower_case_names)

def move():
    graph.append(random.randint(0,SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    graph_canvas.append(random.randint(0,SCREEN_HEIGHT))

    # run again after 100ms (0.1s)
    root.after(100, move)

# --- main --- (lower_case names)

# data at start
data = [random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT) for _ in range(NUMBER)]

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=SCREEN_WIDTH, height=SCREEN_HEIGHT, bg='#ccffcc')
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

graph = Graph(canvas, data)

graph_canvas = GraphCanvas(root, data, width=SCREEN_WIDTH, height=SCREEN_HEIGHT, bg='#ffcccc')
graph_canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

# start animation    
move()

root.mainloop()
```

Using class you can easily add more graphs

[image]